# USB emulated CDROM drive is not automounting (repurposed U3 smart USB stick)

Tags: 12.04, usb, 13.04, automount

I've used `u3-tool` to load a ISO onto my 2MB USB stick. If I'm running 13.04 or 12.04 and I place the flash drive in my PC, the remaining ~923MB fat32 partition auto-mounts, but not the emulated USB-CDROM part. I retested this in an old 9.10 (or 9.04?) system and both partitions were auto-mounted.

Since these awesome flash drives are pretty rare nowadays, I'm wondering if this is a bug or the expected behavior. If it's a bug, what data would I gather before submitting a bug report?

Workaround and more info:

The drive is clearly recognized in `dmesg` and you can (as root) create a mount point with `mkdir` and then mount it using the `mount` command.

As a normal user, you can ask root to install `pmount`, and then:

```
ls -ltr /dev/sr*  #lists CDROM drives by reverse date, you probably want the newest.

pmount /dev/sr1   #mount the drive automagicly on /media/sr1 as type iso9660
```

Comment: focusing on the searchterm "GET_EVENT and TUR disagree continuously" I've found these pages -https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=717249#c3   http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=79b9677d885d1a792bc103f2febb06f91f92de43  - which point at why behavior changed from 9.10 or 9.04 to 12.04

Comment: further progress toward solving my own problem is that this is most likely a `udev` issue. I can write a custom rule, but to fix it upstream I'll need to submit a patch for one of the files in `/lib/udev/rules.d`